# Seeing through objects

Tags: double-vision

Recently I found out that my eyesight is slightly different than most people I know. It's rather hard to explain, so I hope it makes sense.

I see through all objects. All day. All the time. When I put my finger about 30cm away from my face and I focus on a point behind my finger, I see my finger twice, without having to concentrate on it. It is not possible for me in any way other than closing one eye to see my finger 'blurry' and 'centered' like how it would be considered normal I guess? The problem is that this happens all day. Everything I do all day is focussing on stuff which makes everything between me and that object 'transparent' and makes me see it twice.

A good example is playing pool. When I look at the ball I am going to want to pot, I see my cue and the white ball 'double' and am unable to make the shot. When I focus on the white ball, the ball I want to pot is 'double' and I can not get a clear 'line' of where the ball will go.

I only found out recently that this is not a normal way of seeing things, and I can not seem to find anything related to this topic on the internet. My questions are:

- 'Is this normal?'
- 'Is this dangerous?'
- 'Should I do anything about it?'

Comment: Sounds normal to me... But I'll let someone else explain this who can better explain what is happening

Answer (score 2):

This isn't normal, you might have misaligned eyes like my grandmother had, who had similar symptoms to you when she was younger. It was corrected with minor surgery later on in her life.

This is definitely something to talk to your GP or Optometrist about!